# How to parse an HTML table based crossword puzzle and solve it using regex searches through predefined answer lists?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, html-table, userscripts

I am trying to make a Greasemonkey script that automatically fills in the answers in a crossword puzzle by using a regular expression search through lists of possible answers. The Example HTML is too big to put in this post so I'll just link to a jsfiddle that I made with the example in it:
https://jsfiddle.net/popcornrulez/zkxy30or/

`code placeholder`

The main roadblock that I can't get past is how to go about parsing the data from the crossword. If I could do that then I'm pretty sure that I could figure out the rest of the script.

---

## UPDATE:

Thanks to [Niet the Dark Absol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol) and his extremely helpful [jsFiddle contribution](https://jsfiddle.net/zkxy30or/1/) the only thing that I need to figure out now is how to parse the crossword answer Categories so that I can run the regex strings through more specific arrays of possible answers.

EXAMPLE HTML:

```
<div class="cross_q">
<span>Across:</span> 1.Equipment. 3.Artifact. 5.Equipment. 6.Monster. 7.Bold Artifact.
<br />
<span>Down:</span> 1.Monster. 2.Boss-Monster. 4.Strong Monster.</div>
```

I need to have resulting variables similar to what I have below:

```
var 1a = "equipment",
    3a = "artifact",
    5a = "equipment",
    6a = "monster",
    7a = "boldArtifact",
    1d = "monster",
    2d = "bossMonster",
    4d = "strongMonster";
```

Comment: Do you HAVE to use regular expressions?

Comment: Neat puzzle. Consider me nerd-sniped, but here's what I came up with: https://jsfiddle.net/zkxy30or/1/ - I suggest you read through it and try to understand how it all works before you use it yourself.

Comment: Using regexp to match against markup languages are always a bad idea, because of the nested nature of the language.
Use dedicated libraries…

Comment: +Gaétan RYCKEBOER I just need to get the characters that are provided for each answer and then run a search against whatever category the answer is in. i.e. : if the crossword puzzle gave me a string like #ig#t (right) where the # symbols represent blank spots in the puzzle that I need to fill in, I would do a basic `/.ig.t/i` search through a list on possible answers

Comment: +Niet the Dark Absol That really helps me a lot. I need to run the resulted hint strings through their respectives category lists, in order to do that I need to be able to parse the text that says what category each hint is in  (Across: 1.Equipment 3.Artifact) I changed your code so that it marks the empty input cells with a `.`. that way I can directly form the hints into regex strings that I will use to search for the answer in an array of strings. here's the jsfiddle that I currently am at (thanks to your help :) ) [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/popcornrulez/0ttvjh85/2/)